# Statement with no effect

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that do maths like that.
I'll give an example to clarify what I mean.

If a num*2 > 10, I want the program to take it as ((2*num2 % 10)+1).
For example the number 7.
7*2=14 BUT I am trying to let the program take it as 1+4.
So I tried doing that with if statements and gives me an error, my code is below:

```
if ( num8*2 > 10) {
    num8 = ((num8 % 10 ) +1);
   ( num7*2 > 10);
    num7 = ((num7 % 10 ) +1);
   ( num6*2 > 10);
    num6 = ((num6 % 10 ) +1);
   ( num5*2 > 10);
    num5 = ((num5 % 10 ) +1);
   ( num4*2 > 10);
    num4 = ((num4 % 10 ) +1);
   ( num3*2 > 10);
    num3 = ((num3 % 10 ) +1);
   ( num2*2 > 10);
    num2 = ((num2 % 10 ) +1);
   ( num1*2 > 10);
    num1 = ((num1 % 10 ) +1);
}
```

Comment: Do you simply want to add 2 digits?

Comment: Not simply add 2 digits, as i described i want to multiply the number by 2 and if the answer is > 10 i want to add the digits themselves of the answer. Like lets say the number 9... 9*2=18...... 18 > 10 , then we do it like that :(1+8)

Comment: The statement `(num7*2 > 10);` has no effect; did you intend to use `else if  (num7*2 > 10)` (or maybe you don't need the `else`)?  Similarly for the other conditions.  Beware the semicolon I removed. It looks like you need to use an array and a loop, too.

Comment: Each digit is multiplied by 2, and all the digits of the results are joined together.  If the result of multiplying the digit by 2 is two digits, then each of the two digits of the result is summed (i.e. the two-digit number is separated into two single-digit numbers, which are connected to all other digits)

Comment: @Newbie to Coding what I understood is you want to multiply a number with `2` and if the result is greater than `10` you want the `sum` of all the digits result have.

Comment: Exactly, can you help me how can i do that?

Comment: "*doing that with if statements*" the code shows exactly **one** and **only** one `if`-statement: `if ( num8*2 > 10)`

Comment: It seems that your main problem is hidden. Would you mind to show us more of your code? A [example] would be best. While you're reading the linked page, please consider to take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept another method, try this one below:

```
product = initialNumber * 2;
finalResult = 0;
while(product > 9){
    finalResult += product%10;
    product /= 10;
}
finalResult += product;
```

I am simply getting the number multiplied by `2`, then adding all digits of the product.

From your code, there are few discrepancies, such ac as statements in parenthesis not doing much, since they do not modify or assign any value/variable. I guess they were supposed to be `else if` statements?